I am trying to create a vector art of a baseball field but it does not make sense
I am not a native of a country where baseball is a thing, so I never watched to a baseball game in person and I know almost nothing about the game.
I am given the task to creating a baseball field vector art using illustrator.
I have squeezed the web and come with this picture:

What I don't understand is this: the dashed lines have 90ft each, and so the opposite sides, but if I place a square there I get what is shown in the second picture.

I tried that with several images downloaded from the web. Same problem.
If I distort the square to fit the drawing, the inferior sides will not have the same size and the upper sides and the base at each corner will be parallelograms instead of squares, as the real ones.
How in the hell is a baseball field designed?

Wouldn't you bet better asking this on Sports Stack Exchange? I am in the same boat as you. Baseball is not a common sport in my part of the world, and I don't know if this is just a bad diagram, or if it's not actually supposed to be a square.

As I read it, it's not really about the sport @BillyKerr but rather about how to match the diagram. You don't necessarily need to know the sport to recreate that diagram.

@Scott, sure, but the diagram doesn't match a square, and so there's no way to know what was intended. Is it a bad diagram? Or is it not supposed to be a precise square anyway, or perhaps it doesn't really matter either way. Someone who's really into baseball might be better placed to answer this question definitively.

@BillyKerr that's why you look at the numbers and essentially ignore they actual image. e.g each side of the baseball diamond is 90ft long. It doesn't really matter if, in that image, that's not visually accurate. You just need to use 90ft for scale. All the numbers are there. You technically don't need to see any of the actual paths.

You don't need to know the sport with that diagram. It lays out the entire field with measurements. The image you found is slightly distorted for some reason. You are correct, if you try and trace that diagram things do not line up as they should. So...
I would use the measurements as opposed to tracing anything.

Additional labels added to help those unfamiliar with the game.
I used 1ft = 1pt for the scale, drew the square, circles and reference lines all based on what the field diagram shows for numbers. I didn't even look at the image for paths I just read the numbers from the diagram. Then I rotated everything -45° to get the diamond.
Forget it's baseball.. and just look at it like a diagram you need to rebuild.
After you get the basic framework in place, it may also help to just look at other images of baseball fields to get a more aesthetic impression. Once you get the basic diamond and base placements, there's some leeway in terms of visuals or how aspects are visually represented.
In general, the field is primarily grass, but the paths between bases, the area around the bases, the pitcher's mound, and the area behind home base, are all dirt.

Thanks for the explanation. My doubt started when I compared several diagrams and all showed the same problem of not matching the area that in theory was said to be a square. Thanks for clarifying that it is a square, indeed.

I have realized that the center of your circles are not in the square corners. Is that intentional? How off center are they?

The circles (other than pitchers mound) are centered at intersections (using smart guides in Illustrator) (Larger view selected showing they are centered)

@Scott its a visual balance type illusion.

Thanks that helped a lot.
